# Rewrite a url string to corresponding folders

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to have beautiful url and at the same time hide my folder structure,
I want the first Url to point to second Url,

1. image/f1_f2_girl.jpg
2. img/f1/f2/girl.jpg

I tried following but it did not work;

```
RewriteRule ^image\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ img\/$1\/$2\/$3
```

how can I do Such using htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You regex needs to match for underscores in the regex pattern:

```
RewriteEngine On

# disable direct access:
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+img/[^/]+/[^/]+/.+?\.jpg\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]

RewriteRule ^image/([^_]+)_([^_]+)_(.+?\.jpg)$ /img/$1/$2/$3 [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: Thanks, and how can I prevent the direct access to those images? I mean disable accessing the images from this url "img/f1/f2/girl.jpg". Thank you

Comment: ok see updated rules for a way to block direct access to `/img/...` URLs

Comment: Is it possible that I show a 404 page, instead of a access forbidden page?

Answer (score 0):

In your first URL you have `_` not `/`.
And final `.jpg` (with `.`)

```
RewriteRule ^image/([a-z0-9]+)_([a-z0-9]+)_([a-z0-9.]+)$ img/$1/$2/$3  [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, and how can I prevent the direct access to those images? I mean disable accessing the images from this url "img/f1/f2/girl.jpg". Thank you

Comment: If you do not use a visible redirection (eg 302) user can't see the final link, no need to block them, because they don't know the real name...